# Gensim: cannot import name 'Phraser'

Tags: python, gensim

It may be very basic problem but i have stuck with this since 2 hours.
I am trying to execute below line of code:

```
from gensim.models.phrases import Phrases , Phraser
```

but i am getting error: *cannot import name 'Phraser'* as for as i know we get this kind of error when *Phraser* is neither variable nor function in *gensim.models.phrases* but i have checked gensim's homepage and found this:

> class gensim.models.phrases.Phraser(phrases_model)

I have gensim's latest module 0.13.4 and i am using Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit), on windows 10.

Comment: I've tested it on Ubuntu using virtualenv. It's working fine. Do you use virtualenv?

Comment: No, i am using Anaconda distribution on Windows 10.

Comment: Go to where gensim is stored in Anaconda (on macOS for me pip packages are stored in /anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/) Then follow down; models, phrases and see if `Phraser` is in there?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to import Phraser like this on Windows 8:

```
from gensim.models.phrases import Phraser
```

Using Anaconda with Python 2.7 and gensim 1.0.1